# Is there any difference in meaning between "go on a job interview" and "go to a job interview"?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference in meaning between *go on a job interview* and *go to a job interview*? For example:

> I'm going **to** a job interview tomorrow.
>
> I'm going **on** a job interview tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wouldn't normally say "going *on* a job interview" - that sounds like someone has mixed up their prepositions.

We would say either:

- "I'm going *to* a job interview tomorrow"
- "I *have* a job interview tomorrow"

We use "on" when the object of the sentence is something ongoing, something you would be part of, or literally 'on', for example:

- I'm going on a journey
- I'm going on holiday/vacation
- I'm going on a train
- I'm going on a television programme.

A situation related to an interview where you might use "on" is if you were part of a group conducting it:

- I'm on an interview panel tomorrow.